# Refreshing existing windows in Java Swing

Tags: java

I am trying to build a easy Java Swing program where you type in your forename and surname.

There are two buttons `save` and `newDialog`. The `save` button saves the typed names into a class named Person. The `newDialog` button opens a new window with the saved names already printed. My problem is that I want the old windows to also refresh and show the saved names in the textfield. How could I do this? Thank you all!

```
public class PersonFrame extends JFrame {   
    Person p = new Person();

    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(Person.getForename());
    JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(Person.getSurname());
    JButton save = new JButton("Save");
    JButton newDialog = new JButton("NewDialog");

    public PersonFrame() {
        setTitle("Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Forename"));
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Surname"));
        myPanel.add(tf1);
        myPanel.add(tf2);
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                p.setForename(tf1.getText());
                p.setSurname(tf2.getText());
            }
        });

        newDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myPanel);
                PersonFrame personFrame = new PersonFrame();
                personFrame.pack();
                personFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        myPanel.add(save);
        myPanel.add(newDialog);
        this.getContentPane().add(myPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PersonFrame personFrame = new PersonFrame();
        personFrame.pack();
        personFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Person Class:

```
public class Person {   
    private static String forename;
    private static String surname;

    public void setForename(String forename) {
        Person.forename = forename;
    }

    public void setSurname(String nachname) {
        Person.surname = nachname;
    }

    public static String getSurname() {
        if(Person.surname == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            return Person.surname;
        }
    }

    public static String getForename() {
        if(Person.forename == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return Person.forename;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be for your Person class to implement `ChangeListener`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html

Then, every place that uses an information from person would call `person.addChangeListener(this);`.

In every setter of the person class you should call `stateChanged` to notify your listeners that `Person` has changed.

Every time the windows/screens receive the event from changeListener, they should refresh the proper components (for ex, in a JLabel, you would call `label.setText(person.getSurname());`.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. Could you have a look on my new code?

Comment: Sure, but it is common courtesy to upvote / mark the answer that helped you. We use reputation as bounties for our questions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first thank your for your great advice Guilherme Mussi.

I change my code the following way. But now the names are not getting saved anymore. I do not really know what i did wrong.

```
public class PersonFrame extends JFrame{

Person p = new Person();

JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();
JButton save = new JButton("Save");
JButton newDialog = new JButton("NewDialog");

public PersonFrame() {
    setTitle("Frame");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    myPanel.add(new JLabel("Forename"));
    myPanel.add(new JLabel("Surname"));
    tf1.setText(Person.getForename());
    tf2.setText(Person.getSurname());
    myPanel.add(tf1);
    myPanel.add(tf2);
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            p.setForename(tf1.getText());
            p.setSurname(tf2.getText());
        }
    });

    newDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myPanel);
            PersonFrame personFrame = new PersonFrame();
            personFrame.pack();
            personFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    myPanel.add(save);
    myPanel.add(newDialog);
    this.getContentPane().add(myPanel);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    PersonFrame personFrame = new PersonFrame();
    personFrame.pack();
    personFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Person Class:

```
public class Person {

private static String forename;
private static String surname;


public void setForename(String forename) {
    ChangeListener changingForename = new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            Person.forename = forename;
        }
    };
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    ChangeListener changingSurename = new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            Person.surname = surname;
        }
    };

}

public static String getSurname() {
    if(Person.surname == null){
        return null;
    } else {
        return Person.surname;
    }
}
public static String getForename() {
    if(Person.forename == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return Person.forename;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, there are a few things wrong. 1) Your fields forname and surname are static. They should not be.

Comment: 2) In the methods setForname and setSurname, the content should be more or less like this: `this.surname = surname;` and `this.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this))`

Comment: 3) The class PersonFrame should implement changeListener `class PersonFrame implements ChangeListener`

Comment: please mark my other answer as the correct one. There will still be a few things wrong. But you will get there.

Comment: Everywhere, you are using Person statically, like Person.forname. You should use `p.getSurname()` for example

Comment: In your class Person, should should have a `List<ChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();` and a method `void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);`

Comment: I will try to make a gist and send you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code:

```
package temp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Person {
    private String surname;
    private String forename;

    private List<ChangeListener> changeListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        changeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
        for (ChangeListener listener : changeListeners) {
            listener.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
        }
    }

    public String getForename() {
        return forename;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename) {
        this.forename = forename;
        for (ChangeListener listener : changeListeners) {
            listener.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
        }
    }

}
```

Frame class:

```
package temp;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class PersonFrame extends JFrame implements ChangeListener {
    Person p = new Person();

    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();
    JButton save = new JButton("Save");
    JButton newDialog = new JButton("NewDialog");

    JLabel fornameLabel = new JLabel("Forename");
    JLabel surnameLabel = new JLabel("Surname");

    public PersonFrame() {
        setTitle("Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        myPanel.add(fornameLabel);
        myPanel.add(surnameLabel);
        tf1.setText(p.getForename());
        tf2.setText(p.getSurname());
        myPanel.add(tf1);
        myPanel.add(tf2);

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                p.setForename(tf1.getText());
                p.setSurname(tf2.getText());
            }
        });

        p.addChangeListener(this);

        newDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myPanel);
                PersonFrame personFrame = new PersonFrame();
                personFrame.pack();
                personFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        myPanel.add(save);
        myPanel.add(newDialog);
        this.getContentPane().add(myPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PersonFrame personFrame = new PersonFrame();
        personFrame.pack();
        personFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        fornameLabel.setText(p.getForename());
        surnameLabel.setText(p.getSurname());
    }
}
```

I made the values be stored on the labels. I think you will know how to move forward from here on out. If you have further questions, please make a new question.